# Google adsense : personally identifiable information (PII)

Tags: adsense

Hi i have received from google adsense this email and i have fix :

"We have detected ad requests with personally identifiable information (PII). Sending PII to Google violates the AdSense program policies. Please review the list of violating URLs sent to your account email."

And two week late i have received another email :

"We haven't detected any ad requests with personally identifiable information (PII) in the last couple days. We will continue to monitor your ad requests to ensure PII is not sent."

So is the second email meaning i have passed ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the second one mains you have fixed the violation.